# Not Finding JSON ARRAY value within the JSON Object in JAVA - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, json

I am obtaining a JSON response from an API which contains color information.

This is the response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRnGU.png)

I want to be able to access the html_code value from the background_colors array within the info JSON object.

Firstly, have tried doing this simply with this code:

```
result = stack.getBody().getObject().toString(2);
           JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(_result);
           JSONArray jr = parentObject.getJSONArray("results");
           JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(0);
           System.out.print(jb1);
```

This prints me out the info Object as expected.

However, if I try and access the JSON Array "background_colors" using this,

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(_result);
            JSONArray jr = parentObject.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(0);
            System.out.print(jb1);
            JSONArray jsonArray = 
            jb1.getJSONArray("background_colors");
            System.out.print(jsonArray);
```

I get this error: No value for "background_colors".

I know this error means that the background_colors array does not exist in the JSONObject but I have no idea how and why this would be the case?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `background_colors` is a property of the `info` object not the root object from the array.

Answer (score 1):

`background_colors` is a property of the `info` object not the root object from the array.

Try this:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(_result);
JSONArray jr = parentObject.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("info");
JSONArray jsonArray = jb1.getJSONArray("background_colors");
System.out.print(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jb1 = jr.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("info");
JSONArray jsonArray = jb1.getJSONArray("background_colors");
```